# I need to add @ to a role in the command

Tags: discord.js

If I use a command like this, then it will not work:
!role @Nick#0000 @role
How can I fix it?

I tried to use
message.mentions.members.first()
,but i think i was doing it wrong

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return message.reply();
  let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
  if(!rMember) return message.reply("nope.");
  let role = args.join(" @").slice(22);
  if(!role) return message.reply("nope!");
  let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, role);
  if(!gRole) return message.reply("nope.");
  if(rMember.roles.has(gRole.id)) return message.reply("nope.");
  await(rMember.removeRoles(['id', 'id']));
  await(rMember.addRole(gRole.id));

  try{
    await rMember.send(`nope ${gRole.name}!`)
  }catch(e){
  }
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "role"
}
```

So I don't have any result now.

Comment: To get the roles mentionned in your message, you could use `message.mentions.roles, this should be easier than parsing it and searching by name. Could you also describe what doesn't work with your code ? Could you post the error message you get, if any ?

Comment: My code is right, but I asking, how to use my command with mention of role, to use it faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the npm package used in this answer. I've included it to present the simplest and easiest solution I see. This answer does not intend to promote the package itself in any way.</sup>

To check if a certain argument or string is a mention and extract the member/role/channel, you can use [`discord-mentions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-mentions).

```js
const getMention = require('discord-mentions');

try {
  if (!args[1]) return await message.reply('Please provide a user.');
  if (!args[2]) return await message.reply('Please provide a role.');

  let member;
  if (getMention(args[1])) member = getMention(args[1], message.guild).member;
  else member = message.guild.members.find(m => m.user.tag === args[1]);

  if (!member) return await message.reply('Invalid user.');

  let role;
  if (getMention(args[2])) role = getMention(args[2], message.guild).role;
  else role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === args[2]);

  if (!role) return await message.reply('Invalid role.');

  // Continue on... 'member' is a GuildMember, 'role' is a Role.
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: since this block of code is using the `await` keyword, it needs to be called inside a `async` function.

Comment: Declare your callback as async. `async (bot, message, args) => {...}`. For more about async functions, check out [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'discord-mentions'

Comment: `npm i discord-mentions`